# For-Loop Segmentation -- Excessive run ( i < SIZE, but i = SIZE)

Tags: c++, linux, user-interface, for-loop, gnome

This is a function in a program replicating Sierpinski's gasket. This function is supposed to attach the points in the triangle for the fractal.

After much deliberation I've figured out where the issue lies:

```
void add_pts(int &x, int &y)
{ 
    Vector_ref<Rectangle> pt;
    for (int i = 0; i < POINTS; ++i)
    {
         pt_test; //generates changing x, y vals within the limits of the triangle
         cout << "pass" << i <<endl;
         pt.push_back(new Rectangle(Point(x,y),5,5));
         pt[i].set_fill_color(Color::yellow);
         win.attach(pt[i]); 
    }
}
```

The output is "pass1...pass[POINTS-1]", but for whatever reason it runs when i = POINTS and runs into the segmentation error. I have no clue as to why. Can anyone assist, please?

Here is my code. The pt_test and coord are a bit sloppy but seeing as it can't run properly it's very hard to ascertain what I can streamline.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <time.h>
#include "Simple_window.h"
#include "Graph.h"
#include "Point.h"
#include "GUI.h"
#include "Window.h"
using namespace std;
using namespace Graph_lib;

// globals

const int POINTS = 5000;
unsigned int seed = (unsigned int)time(0);
Simple_window win(Point(100,100),1100,700,"Homework 9");

// function declarations

double random(unsigned int &seed);
bool coords(int &x, int &y);
void pt_test(int x, int y);
void add_pts(int &x, int &y);

int main()
{

    int x, y;

    // title

    Text title(Point(400,50), "The Sierpinski Gasket");
    title.set_font(Graph_lib::Font::helvetica_bold);
    title.set_font_size(25);
    title.set_color(Color::cyan);
    win.attach(title);

    // triangle

    Closed_polyline tri;
    tri.add(Point(250,75)); // A
    tri.add(Point(850,75)); // B
    tri.add(Point(550,675)); // C
    tri.set_fill_color(Color::white);
    tri.set_color(Color::dark_red);
    tri.set_style(Line_style(Line_style::solid,3));
    win.attach(tri);

    // vertices
    Text vert_a(Point(225,70), "A (250, 75)");
    vert_a.set_font(Graph_lib::Font::helvetica_bold);
    vert_a.set_font_size(15);
    vert_a.set_color(Color::cyan);
    Text vert_b(Point(855,70), "B (850, 75)");
    vert_b.set_font(Graph_lib::Font::helvetica_bold);
    vert_b.set_font_size(15);
    vert_b.set_color(Color::cyan);
    Text vert_c(Point(575,670), "C (550, 675)");
    vert_c.set_font(Graph_lib::Font::helvetica_bold);
    vert_c.set_font_size(15);
    vert_c.set_color(Color::cyan);

    win.attach(vert_a);
    win.attach(vert_b);
    win.attach(vert_c);

    // point selection

    add_pts(x, y);

    // window title and display

    win.wait_for_button();

}

double random(unsigned int &seed)
{
    const int MODULUS = 15749;
    const int MULTIPLIER = 69069;
    const int INCREMENT = 1;
    seed = ((MULTIPLIER*seed)+INCREMENT)%MODULUS;
    return double(seed)/double(MODULUS);
}

bool coords(int &x, int &y) // generates the points
{
    x = int(251 + 600*random(seed));
    y = int(76 + 600*random(seed));
    if( y > (2*x-425) && x<= 550 || x>=550 && y < (-2*x + 1775))
        return true;
}

void pt_test(int x, int y) // tests the points until they are within the range
{
    coords;
    while(coords == 0)
        coords;
}

void add_pts(int &x, int &y) // attaches the points as shapes
{ 
    Vector_ref<Rectangle> pt;
    for (int i = 0; i < POINTS; ++i)
    {
         pt_test;
     cout << "i == " << i << "  points == " << POINTS << endl;
         pt.push_back(new Rectangle(Point(x,y),5,5));
         pt[i].set_fill_color(Color::yellow);
         win.attach(pt[i]); 
    }
}
```

I've also noticed that the function add_pts doesn't work when the body is in the loop, but if you put the body in int_main(), it runs indefinitely but doesn't reach the segmentation fault as quickly, if at all.

Comment: Maybe also output `POINTS` on that line? Perhaps it has a different value than you think it has?

Comment: Is `pt_test` a macro? How is it defined? Same question for `POINTS`.

Comment: Are you sure that `i = POINTS` at some point and that it isn't crashing for a different reason? You said the output is `"pass1...pass[POINTS-1]"`. Also, does the output start at `1` like that?

Comment: We'll need an MCVE for this one. There's no reason in this code to break by itself.

Comment: What is a `Vector_ref`? What does `attach` do?

Comment: I added my original code. And oops, starts at 0.
vector_ref I thought was just a type of vector. I don't have my text with me, but I copied what I did essentially from the book, with some alterations. attach attaches the shape, which are the points. My last step will be to change it to proper 1x1 pixels, but right now, I'm using a bigger rectangle. I verified POINTS -- its values stays at 5000, with the error occurring at i = 4999. Also, not sure if I understand MCVE -- I'm not sure how to replicate the issue, as I've had many successful loops prior.

Thanks all.

Comment: Also -- I changed my check such that a space would be added AFTER the win.attach(pt), the last line of the loop. This confirms that there's an issue with i == 5000, I believe.